# Express the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ by the relation $(x,y) \equiv (-x,-y)$ as the quotient of a polygon

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, quotient-spaces

This is another old qualifying exam question, and I'm kinda grasping at straws for this one.

> Let $\mathbb{T}^2$ denote the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, and let $M$ denote the quotient of $\mathbb{T}^2$ by the relation $(x,y) \equiv (-x,-y)$.
>
> - Express $M$ as a quotient of a polygon with sides defined.
> - What is the fundamental group of $M$?

So far, what I did was divide the standard quadrilateral expression for $\mathbb{T}^2$ by taking the center to be origin of my coordinate system and then adjusting the sides to get what should be the new quotient on the sides that correspond to $M$ as shown below:

[image: Image for torus division]

After that, I realized that the relation for $M$ would "rotate" the left half of this image into the right half which, after the relations for $M$ are then added to the centerline, would result in the polygon given by
[image: Rotated polygon]

but at this point, I get really stuck. I'm not even sure if what I've done is the correct way to approach this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second diagram looks correct to me.

And then one can see that the quotient is homeomorphic to $S^2$, by simply gluing side pairs of the second diagram one-pair-at-a-time.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much, professor! I'm glad that I wasn't losing my mind.